# Replacing unordered buttons with divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a Instafeed JS code that basically displays my latest posts on my site, but the issue that I'm coming across is that my unordered list circles are popping up when their not supposed to.

Here is the live preview (http://www.eventsinstlouis.com/promote.html/) and hover over one of the pictures and you will see the unordered list circles pop up.

Could I replace the ul and li tags with div and still keep the same formatting?

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

[image]

I believe the answer lies within:

```
template: '<li><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /><ul class="insta-info"><li class="likes">{{likes}}</li><li class="comments">{{comments}}</li></ul></a></li>'
```

Here is the code:

```css
.topiecha-grid {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
  .topiecha-grid .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 3vh;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .topiecha-grid .header::before {
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '\f16d';
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 375px;
    font-size: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(15% - 5px);
    height: calc(50%  - 3px);
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    width: calc(23.35% - 5px);
    height: 100%;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(n + 8) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a > ul.insta-info {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.85);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a > ul.insta-info > li {
    padding: 0 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a > ul.insta-info > li::before {
    margin-right: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a > ul.insta-info > li.likes::before {
    content: '\f004';
    color: red;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a > ul.insta-info > li.comments::before {
    content: '\f086';
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
       object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
            filter: grayscale(0);
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .topiecha-grid > ul > li a:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(70%);
            filter: grayscale(70%);
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
    .topiecha-grid > ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: stretch;
      justify-content: space-around;
      min-width: 100%;
      max-height: none;
      height: auto;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li {
      width: calc(32.5%);
      height: 200px;
      padding: 0;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:first-of-type {
      padding: 0;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
      width: calc(32.5%);
      height: 200px;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(n + 8) {
      display: block;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(n + 10) {
      display: none;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li a > ul.insta-info {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      top: auto;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li a > ul.insta-info > li {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    .topiecha-grid > ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: stretch;
      justify-content: space-around;
      min-width: 100%;
      max-height: none;
      height: auto;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li {
      width: calc(48.5%);
      height: 300px;
      padding: 0;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:first-of-type {
      padding: 0;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
      width: calc(48.5%);
      height: 300px;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(n + 9) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .topiecha-grid > ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: stretch;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: auto;
      max-height: none;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li {
      width: 97%;
      height: 50%;
      margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    }
    .topiecha-grid > ul > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
      width: 98%;
      height: 50%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<section class="sectionTwo pb-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="topiecha-grid">
                        <div class="header">Follow us on instagram</div>
                        <ul id="instafeed"></ul>
                     </div>
                     
                     <!-- JS - instafeed to include instagram content: photos/movies  https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js --> 
                     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/instafeed.js/1.4.1/instafeed.min.js"></script>
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                       var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                         get: 'user',
                         userId: '4698959157',
                         accessToken: '4698959157.1677ed0.9b364775d6b74b48af382e7c8dd1ddca',
                         resolution: 'standard_resolution',
                         template: '<li><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /><ul class="insta-info"><li class="likes">{{likes}}</li><li class="comments">{{comments}}</li></ul></a></li>',
                         sortBy: 'most-recent',
                         limit: 9,
                         links: true
                         /** More options here: https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/   **/
                       });
                       userFeed.run();
                </script>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to remove these circles that appear on the list elements when you hover,

[image: The thing to remove]

This little snipped is all you need to add to your css,

```
#instafeed ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Wow, as easy as that. Thanks for the help Ryan, was working my mind around this for the last hour.

Comment: CSS issues are always like that ;) glad I could help!